# How to pass a parameter to Chef recipe from external source

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm new to Chef and seeking help here. I'm looking into using Chef to deploy our builds to Chef node servers (Windows Server 2012 machines). I have a cookbook called copy_builds that goes out to a central repository and selects the build we want to deploy and copies it out to the node server. The recipe I have contains basic steps that perform the copy steps, and this recipe could be used for all builds we want to deploy except for one thing: the build name.

Here is an example of the recipe:

```
powershell_script 'Copy build files' do
  code '
    $Project = "Dev3_SomeCoolBuild"
    net use "\\\\server\\build_share\\drop\\$Project"
    $BuildNum = GC "\\\\server\\build_share\\drop\\$Project\\buildlabel.txt"
    robocopy \\\\server\\build_share\\drop\\$Project\\bin W:\\binroot\\$BuildNum'
end
```

As you can see, the variable $Project contains the name of the build in this recipe. If we have 100 different builds, all with different names, then what is the best way to handle this without creating 100 different recipes for my copy_builds cookbook?

BTW: this is how I'm currently calling Chef to deploy, which is in a PowerShell script that's external to Chef:

```
knife node run_list set $Node "recipe[copy_builds::$ProjectName],recipe[install_build]"
```

This command (from the external PowerShell script) contains the project/build name info within it's own $ProjectName variable. In this case $ProjectName contains the value of 'Dev3_SomeCoolBuild', to reference the recipe Dev3_SomeCoolBuild.rb.

What I'd like is have just one default recipe under copy_builds cookbook, and pass in the build/project name. Is this possible? And what is the best way to do it? I've read about data bags, attributes, and providers, but not sure if they would work for what I want.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Keith

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for you is likely to use a single recipe that gets a list of projects to deploy from a databag or node attributes (or both). So basically take what you have now and put it in a loop, and then use either roles to set node attributes or put the project mapping into a databag item.

Comment: So if I change by recipe above to something like $Project = "Data_Bag_Item", then how do I call the data bag from my external powershell script if it's already like so: knife node run_list set $Node "recipe[copy_builds::$ProjectName],recipe[install_build]". Do I modify this command? Run an additional knife command? Sorry, just still so new to Chef.

Comment: If you're just starting out, I wouldn't try and do this. Just copy-pasta the recipe as needed. Working with the `data_bag_item` has examples in the Chef docs, but if you don't know Ruby it might be more than you want to bite off.

Comment: I don't mind biting off more and learning about Ruby, so I'll check out the data_bag_item docs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using **attributes** here to solve my problem. I updated my script to write the build name to the attributes/default.rb file for the copy_builds recipe and upload the cookbook to Chef each time a deployment is run.

My recipe now includes a call to the attributes file to get the build name, like so:

```
powershell_script 'Copy build files' do
  code <<-EOH
    $BuildNum = GC \\\\hqfas302002c\\build_share\\drop\\"#{node['copy_builds']['build']}"\\buildlabel.txt
    robocopy \\\\hqfas302002c\\build_share\\drop\\"#{node['copy_builds']['build']}"\\webbin W:\\binroot\\$BuildNum /E
    EOH
end
```

And now my call to Chef looks like this:

```
    knife node run_list set $Node "recipe[copy_builds],recipe[install_build]"
```